# Classic ASP Open directory on server

Tags: asp-classic

I want to open a directory, that sits on a server, through a link.
My problem is that it works perfectly in an .htm page but not in an .asp page.
Here is what i use:

```
<a href="file://server/folder/folder/folder" target="_blank">Foldername</a>
```

I have tried using 3 or 5 slashes after the file: but the same result.
A different thing i found without result is:

```
<a href="file://server/folder/folder" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popupwindow', 'width=400,height=300,scrollbars,resizable'); return false;">Link</a>
```

After trying to figure it out in html i tried the following in asp:

```
<%
str_url="file://server/folder/folder"
Response.Write("<script>") 
Response.Write("window.open('" & str_url & "', 'myWin','height=800,width=1024,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');") 
Response.Write("</script>")
%>
```

But after several attempts to get stuff working i'm still banging my head against the wall. Could this perhaps be a disabled function in IIS7? Or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file:// style links will only work for you on your local machine, you cannot open a folder on a remote server using that method.  (well not unless that path is accessable from your local machine, a server share or somesuch)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you happend to know a way to get it working or is the only option to just put the links in a .htm page?

Comment: You could setup FTP on your server and have the links point to folders available via FTP, failing that you'd need to use the FileSystemObject in ASP to read the folders programatically and display the folder contents in HTML.  You can also enable directory browsing in IIS, that will let you point to a folder containing files and have read only access to them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, didn't think of those yet. I'll get working on your ideas, see what is the best solution. And if all else fails i'll just place the links in a different section of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code to display a directory:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 25px">&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Document</th>
        <th style="width: 60px">Size</th>
    </tr>
    <%
    Dim iCounter, iFileSize
    Dim oFS, oFL
    Dim sDirectory

    sDirectory = "directory/you/want"
    iCounter = 0

    Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFL = oFS.GetFolder(Server.MapPath(sDirectory))

    For Each oF In oFL.Files
        iCounter = iCounter + 1

        iFileSize = FormatNumber(CLng(oF.Size) / 1024 / 1024, 2)
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=iCounter %>.</td>
        <td><a href="<%=sDirectory %>/<%=oF.Name %>" target="_blank"><%=oF.Name %></a></td>
        <td><%=iFileSize %> MiB</td>
    </tr>
    <%
    Next
    %>
</table>
```